# 400 Bad Request sending JSON POST to REST

Tags: java, jquery, json, rest, jersey

I am sending  POST from JQuery using some data, but thru my Javascript I get:

400 Bad Request error and REST not firing

Trying it from Poster I get the following:

HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type.The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.

Here is my JQuery:

```
function doUpdate(path, rdf)
        {
            var encodedRdf = base64_encode(rdf);
            var data = {"path": path, "rdf": encodedRdf};
            var sUrl = "http://localhost:8080/browsing/services/RDF/update";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: sUrl,
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: data,
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                success: function parse(resp, status, xhr) {
                   $("#message").html("STATUS: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText + "\n" + resp);
                   $("#message").hide();
                   $("#login_message").html("<font color='green'><b>Record succesfully updated</b></font>d");
                },
                error: function(resp, status, xhr){
                    $("#message").html("ERROR: " + resp.status + " " + resp.statusText + "\n" + xhr);
                    $("#message").show();
                }
            });
        }
```

Here is my REST Resource:

```
@POST
@XmlElement(name = "data")
@Path("/update")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void update(Data data) {
    ... 
}
```

Here is my Data Object:

```
@XmlRootElement 
public class Data implements Serializable {

     private String path;
     private String rdf;

      /**
     * @return the path
     */
    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }
    /**
     * @param path the path to set
     */
    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }
    /**
     * @return the rdf
     */
    public String getRdf() {
        return rdf;
    }
    /**
     * @param rdf the rdf to set
     */
    public void setRdf(String rdf) {
        this.rdf = rdf;
    }
```

Any one can tell me where is the problem please?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Composing the JSON as follows and stringhifying it solved it!

```
var data = {"path": path, "rdf": encodedRdf};
...
data: JSON.stringify(data),
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the op and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have following init parameter in web.xml;

```
 <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
 </init-param>
```

Comment: Adding this doesn't change anything: TO be moreclear in creating the JSON Object var data = {"path": path, "rdf": encodedRdf}, path and encodedRdf and are passed as parameters. If I put regular strings it does fire and work properly.

Comment: Creating the JSON object, setting the fields and JSON.stringify solved it!